# Accessing the content of an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I know that this questions was already asked a thousand times here on stackoverflow, but i am curious about one thing which i will mention in the end. I resarched the last eight hours just about how to get the source code of an iFrame which i do **not have access to**! Means for example something like this

> my_site.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe id="om_frame" name="om_frame" src="http://google.com"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Lets say, "**my_site.php**" is a website running on my server and i want to be able to see the source code of the iframe which is the source code of google. Yes, i know there is something called the "Same-origin policy" which does not allow you to do so. But the one thing i am curious about is, how does firebug for example do it?
[image]

Firebug is exactly doing what i want to do, and if they somehow are able to access the content then there must be a way to do so. If i am wrong i would be glad if someone would explain this in detail. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simple difference is that Firebug is an extension of the browser and has access to the window but is not contained in the window.

Your code runs inside the window and is under much more restricted security policies